# Visual Studio Code C++ debug break on exception

Tags: c++, vscode-debugger

I am running visual studio code with the C++ v1.7.1 extension installed

[image]

The `launch.json` file specifies `cppdbg`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/test.exe",
              "args": ["windex"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bin",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            //"miDebuggerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to break when and where an exception occurs.  However, I cannot find where to enable this.  There are no exception checkboxes in the breakpoint panel.

[image]

Running on windows 10 using mingw g++ v11.2

How do I enable break on exception?

Comment: might work with the latest insiders build https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1800. One workaround is to put a breakpoint in the exception class constructor instead

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks.  The workaroud seems challenging.  The issue you reference is very recently active, so maybe there will soon be a fix in the next update?  In the meantime, I tracked down the particular problem.  So I will wait in hope of a fixed update - I need this feature regularly

Comment: Linked to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7316